# Universal 2-bit gates

Tags: propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I'd like to show that there is no set of 2 bit reversible gates which is universal. I'm not sure as to where & how do I start here? I tried to assume by contradiction that such a set exists, thus it can implement both $OR$ ($\vee$) and $AND$ ($\wedge$), and then since each of the gates used is reversible, I thought going backwards, and to get the original entry values $X,Y$ out of the value of $X\wedge Y$, in a contradiction to $AND$ not being reversible. But I'm not sure if its ok? Or perhaps there is another way to prove so?

Comment: What is a reversible gate? If I understand this correctly, no two-argument gate can be reversible, since the codomain is strictly smaller than the domain.

Comment: A 2-dimensional reversible gate is a function $f: \{0 ,1 \} ^2 \rightarrow \{ 0 , 1\} ^2$ such that there exists a $g: \{0 ,1 \} ^2 \rightarrow \{ 0 , 1\} ^2$ such that for every given $z,w$ there exists exactly one $(x,y)$ such that $g(x,y)=z,w$ (i.e. $g\equiv f^{-1} $, the results of every gate can be reversed to the original input).

Comment: ok, that makes sense. And how do you compose gates together?

Comment: What does "universal" mean in this context? For reversible gates I would expect the natural sense of "universal" to be that every _bijection_ $\{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}^n$ can be produced. Or is it allowed to throw some intermediate results away and use others more than once?

Comment: @HenningMakholm It is allowed to throw some intermediate results away and use gates more than once. But you need to show that every function $f: \{ 0 , 1 \} ^n \rightarrow \{ 0 , 1 \} ^ n $ can be produced, where $f$ doesn't have to be a bijection (the $2-$dimensional gates you use do have to be bijections themselves, but you need to show you can produce **any** boolean gate with them).
"A Logic Gate which can infer any of the gate among Logic Gates. OR a gate which can be use to create any Logic gate is called Universal Gate", and in our case we mean a set of gates.

Answer (score 3):

The truth table of a 2-bit gate will have two input columns and two output columns:

```
 Input | Output
 A  B  |  X  Y
-------+--------
 0  0  |  ?  ?
 0  1  |  ?  ?
 1  0  |  ?  ?
 1  1  |  ?  ?
```

In order for the gate to be reversible, each output column must contain exactly two ones and two zeroes. This limits the possible output columns to one of $\binom42=6$ Boolean functions of $A$ and $B$, namely $A$, $B$, $A \mathbin{\sf XOR} B$, and their negations. So everything that can be computed by a network of arbitrary reversible 2-bit gates can also be computed by a network of NOT and XOR gates.

Knowing this, we can prove by induction on the number of gates that every result of a NOT/XOR network has one of the following relations to each of the network's inputs: *Either* the result does not depend on that input at all, *or* the result will invert whenever that input is inverted.

(In terms of abstract algebra, the possible outputs are always *affine* functions of the input over $\mathbb F_2$).

Because $A\lor B$ does not have this property, it cannot be produced by such a network.

---

On the other hand, **three**-bit reversible gates *are* universal when results can be discarded. Specifically, this particular 3-bit gate which computes $4-x \bmod 2^3$ is universal:

```
 Input | Output
 A B C |  X Y Z
-------+---------
 0 0 0 |  1 0 0
 0 0 1 |  0 1 1
 0 1 0 |  0 1 0
 0 1 1 |  0 0 1
 1 0 0 |  0 0 0
 1 0 1 |  1 1 1
 1 1 0 |  1 1 0
 1 1 1 |  1 0 1
```

Wiring all three inputs of this gate together will produce a steady `0` on the $Y$ output, and feeding this `0` to the $A$ input of another gate will make it produce $B\mathbin{\sf NOR}C$, which is known to be universal.